# YN622TX on X1 hotshoe?

Tags: canon, yongnuo

I have YN685's and a 622tx ... just bought a Godox AD600BM with an X1c trigger. 
My question - how do I get the 622tx to operate the 685 flashes while stacked atop the x1 hotshoe? I have had several attempts but it is very flakey with the 622TX refusing to respond to commands when attached to the x1 (which is on my 5D3)
Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Someone on DPreview reports that stacking a YN-622-TX on top of an X1T works with the lights in manual mode. ([link](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/59405475))

But the X1T's hotshoe is not a true TTL passthrough hotshoe. It is basically a slave in Group A, [according to folks on POTN](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1455540). Trying to use it to stack a non single-pin flash or trigger on top of the X1T may not work, because it will not have full hotshoe communication with the camera.

Or you could get a YN-622 transceiver and stack the X1T on top of that. The 622s have true passthrough hotshoes. They just don't have the nice LCD screen to display/control settings, so you'll probably have to use the camera's flash control menu to set the YN-685s.

Your best bet would probably be to get Godox X1R-C receivers for your YN-685s, or to trade them in for Godox TT685 or V860II speedlights.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response - much appreciated - my workaround is to use the Godox AD600 in optical manual mode triggered by the YN685 flashes I'm controlling with the 622TX - it's a bit of a kludge but very annoyed that the guy at the photo shop I purchased from definitively said it should be used as a pass through hotshoe with the 622TX :-(

Comment: @Rob my sympathies, particularly since the AD600's a TTL/HSS light. Very annoying. Just occurred to me, though: you _could_ try stacking the X1T on top of a YN-622 transceiver. The 622/622ii has a true passthrough hotshoe. Will edit.